# Is there dark mode for mobile on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, design, mobile-web

Now I have chosen the mobile version from the PC, and I no longer see it with overlapping bugs... But I wonder, is there dark mode for the mobile version on Stack Overflow?

Right now what I see is this:

[image]

And if there isn't, are there any plans for this?

Comment: Note that the responsive view on mobile *does* [respect/ implement dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQF8L.png).

Comment: What is *"the compu"*?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q "compu" is a short name for "computadora". It means computer / PC.

Comment: @zcoop - how do I use the responsive view?

Comment: @Bee On mobile, scroll down to the very bottom of the page and click ["full site" in the site footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19uBX.png).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no dark mode available for the mobile theme and there are not any plans to ever bring it to the mobile theme. We plan to eventually deprecate and remove the mobile web layout in favor of the responsive layout, once that layout is more refined and available for all pages.

Answer (score 3):

You can instead use Opera's dark mode or Firefox + some dark theme extension such as Dark Reader:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aside from that, congratulations on earning 20K here!

Comment: Could you update the screenshots to show that it works with the current mobile website?

Comment: @Laurel Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGD81.png Opera's dark mode stopped working a few days ago on my phone (not just SE but any website) but it used to work fine till then.